# Filter events by owner fields - Calendar plugin

Tags: calendar, plugin-calendar

I'm using Michael Rog's [*Craft Calendars*](https://calendars.docs.topshelfcraft.com) plugin.

I'm wondering if it's possible to limit events to specified owner category.

For example, I have a training entry with *trainingType* and *trainingLevel* category type fields.

While listing events is it possible to do something like:

```
{% set params = {
    calendar: 'myAwesomeCalendar',
    dateRangeStart: 'today',
    dateRangeEnd: now|date_modify("+1 month"),
    owner.trainingType = 'webinar',
    owner.trainingLevel = 'expert' 
} %}

{% for e in craft.calendars.events(params) %}
    <h1>{{ e.owner.title }}</h1>
    <p>Starts: {{ e.startDate  | date("Y-m-d") }}</p>
    <p>{{ e.owner.trainingType }} , {{ e.owner.trainingLevel }}
{% endfor %}
```

If not, how else would you approach this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find info about how to do this in the docs: https://calendars.docs.topshelfcraft.com/guide/events-variable.html#How-it-Works

The *EventCriteriaModel* given by `craft.calendars.events` is used to query the owner elements from which the event instances are generated.

So, in your example above, you can use something like:

```
{% set params = {
    calendar: 'myAwesomeCalendar',
    dateRangeStart: 'today',
    dateRangeEnd: now|date_modify("+1 month"),
    trainingType: 'webinar',
    trainingLevel: 'expert' 
} %}
```

This tells *Calendars*:

- Find entries where `trainingType` is "webinar" and `trainingLevel` is "expert"...
- ...and if those elements have any event rules registered on the Calendar called *myAwesomeCalendar*...
- ...return the instances of those events that occur in the next month.

(In this case, *Calendars* queries Entry elements, since that is the default. You could specify a different element type, however.)